# Why is Jordan normal form possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

We know that we are able to put a 2x2 matrix $A$ into the following Jordan normal form: $A=PJP^{-1}$ with

$J = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & a \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{pmatrix}$

Where $a=0$ or $a=1$.

Of course, if $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, then our matrix $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues, and thus has corresponding linearly independent eigenvectors. Thus putting into Jordan normal form corresponds simply to diagonalisation with $a=0$. The columns of $P$ are the LI eigenvectors of $A$.

The same is possible if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$, but $\lambda$ has geometric multiplicity 2. We may also set the columns of $P$ to be LI vectors corresponding to the $\lambda$ eigenvalue, and we are dagonalising $A$.

If we have $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$ with geometric multiplicity $1$, then we set $a=1$. If we write $P=(c_1,c_2)$ as the columns then $c_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$, and $c_2$ satisfies $(A-\lambda I)c_2 = c_1$. That is, $c_1$ is in the image of $(A-\lambda I)$: the nullspace of this matrix $(A-\lambda I)$ is a basis for the image space.

I am trying to wrap my head around why it makes sense for this to be so, and would appreciate any input!

Comment: Try and conceptualise it in terms of Jordan chains. In the same way we expect a matrix with an eigenvector for each eigenvalue to have a diagonal form, it is nice to think of Jordan chains as natural bases of the space (which indeed they are) by cascading with "generalised" eigenvectors until the geometric multiplicity meets the algebraic multiplicity